# How does one go about evaluating a new loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, log-loss

Suppose a new loss function similar to log loss is proposed. Now we have to check whether it'll work in practical scenarios in general and tractable. What experiments one should run get to some conclusions about the new loss function?